# @Configuration class not being able to use JPA repository during its initialization causing NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a strange issue with a Spring `@Configuration` class: one of the bean defined in it will not find its dependencies.

Here is the `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = new ProviderManager();
        return authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator());
        return expressionHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationPermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator() {
        return new ApplicationPermissionEvaluator(permissionMap());
    }

    private Map<String, Permission> permissionMap() {
        Map<String, Permission> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("updateAdvertisementIsAllowed", advertisementOwnerPermission());
        map.put("advertisementByIdOwnerPermission", advertisementByIdOwnerPermission());

        return map;
    }

    @Bean
    public AdvertisementOwnerPermission advertisementOwnerPermission() {
        return new AdvertisementOwnerPermission();
    }

    @Bean
    public AdvertisementByIdOwnerPermission advertisementByIdOwnerPermission() {
        return new AdvertisementByIdOwnerPermission();
    }


}
```

Here is the `AdvertisementByIdOwnerPermission` bean:

```
@Component
public class AdvertisementByIdOwnerPermission implements Permission {

    @Autowired
    private AdvertisementRepository advertisementRepository;
...
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'advertisementByIdOwnerPermission': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.bignibou.repository.advertisement.AdvertisementRepository com.bignibou.configuration.security.permission.AdvertisementByIdOwnerPermission.advertisementRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.bignibou.repository.advertisement.AdvertisementRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:324)
    at com.bignibou.configuration.security.MethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b8785a07.advertisementByIdOwnerPermission(<generated>)
    at com.bignibou.configuration.security.MethodSecurityConfiguration.permissionMap(MethodSecurityConfiguration.java:49)
    at com.bignibou.configuration.security.MethodSecurityConfiguration.permissionEvaluator(MethodSecurityConfiguration.java:41)
    at com.bignibou.configuration.security.MethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b8785a07.CGLIB$permissionEvaluator$6(<generated>)
    at com.bignibou.configuration.security.MethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b8785a07$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$82172390.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at com.bignibou.configuration.security.MethodSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b8785a07.permissionEvaluator(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.bignibou.repository.advertisement.AdvertisementRepository com.bignibou.configuration.security.permission.AdvertisementByIdOwnerPermission.advertisementRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.bignibou.repository.advertisement.AdvertisementRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.bignibou.repository.advertisement.AdvertisementRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 83 more
```

I can't figure out why Spring won't find the `AdvertisementRepository` defined in the `AdvertisementByIdOwnerPermission` whereas it is properly picked by the rest of the application...

Can anyone please help?

**edit 1**: Information about my Spring Data Jpa usage:

Spring Data Jpa configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.bignibou.repository")
public class JpaConfiguration {

}
```

Interface for Repository:

```
@RooJpaRepository(domainType = Advertisement.class)
public interface AdvertisementRepository {

}
```

**edit 2**: I thought it might have something to do with order of initialization of my configuration classes. I tried adding `@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE + 10)` to my MethodSecurityConfiguration class but it still does not work.

Comment: By the posted code, there's no definition of a class whose name is `AdvertisementRepository` or a class that implementens an interface with name `AdvertisementRepository`, thus Spring cannot inject it.

Comment: Umm. I am not sure I understand you. The above Jpa Repository is a Spring Data JPA repository (see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)).

Comment: Well, there's nothing in your current post that explains you're using spring data jpa... Note that we do not have a magic crystal ball that shows all your project and configurations... So please post all the relevant info (that you think) may help to spot the problem and solve it.

Comment: You might check and make sure that roo has generated the corresponding  AdvertisementRepository_Roo_Jpa_repository.aj aspect file.  Also make sure your AdvertisementRepository interface is in the com.bignibou.repository package.

Comment: @DavidA: Thanks. I can confirm the .aj has been generated and that both the interface and the .aj are located in the `com.bignibou.repository.advertisement` package.

Comment: I previously had problems with the package not being exact (ie. not working with a subpackage).   Yes, very annoying.  Try to move the interface to com.bignibou.repository and see if it works.

Comment: @DavidA: No luck with this either...

Comment: What versions of the org.springframework.data libraries are you using?

Comment: I use version: 1.3.0.RELEASE

Comment: You might give 1.4.0.RELEASE for spring-data-commons-core a try.  You might make sure your logging of org.springframework.data is set to to ALL so you can see what it is doing in detail. Other than that, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I see you are using Spring Roo. Are you using ajc compiler to include the aspects during build time?

Comment: Thanks Geoland. I haven't changed the Roo configuration actually.

Comment: I suspect that by the time the above configuration classes is scanned and initialized, the jpa repository has not yet been proxied by Spring... Does anyone know how to remedy this?

Comment: You can try to use Push-In refactoring to join AdvertisementRepository with it's aspect

Comment: @geoand Thanks. Please note that AdvertisementRepository works fine when used by the rest of the application. Do you really think a push-in refactoring would help?

Comment: @balteo I kind of doubt that it will help, but I think that it's worth a try

Comment: I will give it a try then... In the meantime if someone has another idea, please don't hesitate to share it.

Comment: No luck with push in refactoring either

Comment: Would help if you can post your source code (or atleast create a minimal project that reproduces the problem). It could be classpath scanning or roo associated aspectj weaving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted the issue using the latest version of Spring Data Commons and Spring Data JPA as advised by Oliver Gierke here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23347954/536299

It was actually a small bug in the version of Spring Data I was using.